# Python django, when creating an registering form how to get this .get method working?

Tags: django

I started to watch Corey Schafer's django website tutorial and everything was going great until now. unlike in the video after registering site doesn't sends me to home page. It does nothing. All I suspect is the get method because it is not the color it supposed to be in VSC. Any ideas why :(
and also .method functions seems to be not working it is white in VSC

user_views.py:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
         form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account Created for {username}')
            return redirect("blog-home")
    else:
        form=UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

here is the urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('Blog.urls')),
    path("register/",user_views.register,name="register")
    
    
    ]
```

Blog.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns= [
    path("",views.Home,name="blog-home"),
    path("about/",views.About, name="blog-about"),


]
```

templates:

```
{% extends "Blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class='content-section'>
        <form method='POST'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form_group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outlline-info" type="submit">
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="boder-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#"> Sign In </a>
            </small>

        </div>
    </div>  
{% endblock content %
```

base template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Blog/main.css' %}">
    {% if title %}
        <title> {{title}} </title>
    {% else %}
        <title> Django Project  </title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{%url 'blog-home'%}">Django Blog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
              <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{%url 'blog-home'%}">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
              </div>
              <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{%url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if messages %}
              {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="Alert alert-{{ message.tags}}">
                  {{message}}  </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="content-section">
              <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
              <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                </ul>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the resource?

Comment: The `.get` seems fine. I think it's because `if form.is_valid():` returns `False`. Try to print what `form.errors` is after the `form.is_valid()` call (should be outside the `if form.is_valid()`)

Comment: Can you also show your template? It's also possible you did not set POST in the form

Comment: How do I print errors I am new to debugging and django,sorry

Comment: I added the templates.

Answer (score 1):

People who had a problem with PATH variables before listen me carefully this might save you a lot of time, Although I still don't know why and how. There is a django_settings module which is not present anywhere or maybe I couldn't find the exact folder but however this module can be set to your projects setting module that fixes the problem:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin runserver
```

from the terminal, this sets your path of settings I guess